# Isotope: Create warning if search and filter doesn't give back any result

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I have written an extension for TYPO3. Now i have a problem. Can anyone tell me what i have to do if i want to display a custom warning text-message as soon as the searchstring or dropdown-filter doesn't give back any results? Something like:

"Sorry - we can't find any entries with this search filters!"

Currently my code is looking like this:

```js
    // Isotope Steinlexikon
    $(function() {
        var $container = $('#lexikon-masonry'),
            $select = $('#lexikon-filter select'),
            filters = {};


        var qsRegex;
        var SelectFilter = '*';

        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            // Filter mit Suchfeld
            filter: function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                var SerRes = qsRegex ? $(this).text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
                var SelRes = $(this).is(SelectFilter);
                return SerRes && SelRes;
            }
        });
        // use value of search field to filter
        var $quicksearch = $('#quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
            qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
            $container.isotope();
        }, 200 ) );
        // debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
        function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
            var timeout;
            return function debounced() {
                if ( timeout ) {
                    clearTimeout( timeout );
                }
                function delayed() {
                    fn();
                    timeout = null;
                }
                timeout = setTimeout( delayed, threshold || 100 );
            }
        }

        //fancybox
        $('.fancybox2').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); // Default action ausschalten

            $.fancybox({
                //width: 500,
                //height: 400,
                autoSize: true,
                href: $(this).attr('href'),
                type: 'ajax'
            });
        });


        // Filter mit Select Form

        $select.change(function() {

            var $this = $(this);

            // store filter value in object
            // i.e. filters.color = 'red'
            var group = $this.attr('data-filter-group');

            filters[ group ] = $this.find(':selected').attr('data-filter-value');
            // console.log( $this.find(':selected') )
            // convert object into array
            var isoFilters = [];
            for ( var prop in filters ) {
                isoFilters.push( filters[ prop ] )
            }
            console.log(filters);
            SelectFilter = isoFilters.join('');
            $container.isotope();
            return false;

        });
    });
```

```css
#lexikon-masonry .item {
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 5px;
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px #ccc solid;
    float: left;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
#lexikon-masonry .item img {
 opacity: 1;
}
#lexikon-masonry .item:hover img {
 opacity: 0.5;
}
#lexikon-masonry .image-hover #image-caption {
 position: relative; 
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 bottom: 0px;
 background: #fff;
 z-index: 1;
 opacity: 1;
 text-transform: uppercase;

}
#lexikon-masonry .image-hover:hover #image-caption {
 opacity: 0.8;
}
#lexikon-masonry .image-hover #image-caption span {
 text-transform: none;
}
#lexikon-masonry .image-hover .img-button-link {
 position: absolute; 
 /*left: 50%;
 top: 50%;*/
 margin-left: 110px;
 margin-top: -125px;
 opacity: 0;
}
#lexikon-masonry .image-hover:hover .img-button-link {
 opacity: 1;
}

div#lexikon-filter {
    position:left;
}

div.lexStyled { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    overflow:hidden; /* this hides the select's drop button */ 
    padding:0; 
    margin:0; 
    background: white url(../images/select-down.png) no-repeat bottom right; 
    /* this is the new drop button, in image form */ 
    width:12em; 
 border-radius:2px; 
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
    border: solid 1px #ccc; 
}

div.lexStyled select { 
    width:115% /* this percentage effectively extends the drop down button out of view */; 
    background-color:transparent /* this hides the select's background making any styling visible from the div */; 
    background-image:none; 
    -webkit-appearance: none /* this is required for Webkit browsers */; 
    border:none; 
    box-shadow:none; 
    padding:0.3em 0.5em; /* padding should be added to the select, not the div */ 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
 <div class="row">
  <div id="lexikon-suche" class="col span_3">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" data-filter-value="" id="quicksearch" placeholder="Durchsuchen" />
  </div>
  <div id="lexikon-filter" class="col span_9">
   <div class="lexStyled">
   <select data-filter-group="gestein">
    <option data-filter-value="*" class="selected">Alle Gesteine</option>
                <option data-filter-value=".lagersteine" class="selected">Lagersteine</option>
                <option data-filter-value=".kunststeine" class="selected">Kunststeine</option>

   </select>
   </div>
   <div class="lexStyled">
   <select data-filter-group="farbe">
    <option data-filter-value="*" class="selected">Alle Farben</option>
                <option data-filter-value=".rot" class="selected">Rot</option>
                <option data-filter-value=".gelb" class="selected">Gelb</option>

   </select>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
<br><hr><br>
 <div class="row">
  <div id="lexikon-masonry" class="col span_12">
    <div class="item image-hover lagersteine rot gelb">
     <div id="image-caption" class="name">Test1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item image-hover kunststeine rot">
     <div id="image-caption" class="name">Test2</div>
    </div>
            <div class="item image-hover lagersteine kunststeine gelb">
                <div id="image-caption" class="name">Test3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I did not come through the examples given in these answers ([jQuery Isotope filter to no items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596312/jquery-isotope-filter-to-no-items)). It does not work for me.

Thx for your help

Comment: what did you try, why didn't it work?

Comment: I tried to implement the function as shown in the example of the article i've pasted. but i didn't come trough.

Comment: @madalinivascu do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Isotope instance like this

```
$container.data('isotope')
```

And this has property `$filteredAtoms`, which holds filtered items. So to get count, use this:

```
var visibleItemsCount = $container.data('isotope').$filteredAtoms.length;
```

For **V2**

```
var visibleItemsCount = $container.data('isotope').filteredItems.length;
```

And after filtering, check for visible items. If has some, hide message, show otherwise.

```
// Function to check if filters have some results
function checkResults(){
  var visibleItemsCount = $container.data('isotope').$filteredAtoms.length;

  if( visibleItemsCount > 0 ){
    $('.no-results').hide();
  }
  else{
    $('.no-results').show();
  }
}
```

```js
// Isotope Steinlexikon
    $(function() {
        var $container = $('#lexikon-masonry'),
            $select = $('#lexikon-filter select'),
            filters = {};


        var qsRegex;
        var SelectFilter = '*';

        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            // Filter mit Suchfeld
            filter: function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                var SerRes = qsRegex ? $(this).text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
                var SelRes = SelectFilter == '' || $(this).is(SelectFilter);
                return SerRes && SelRes;
            }
        });
        // use value of search field to filter
        var $quicksearch = $('#quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
            qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
            $container.isotope();
            checkResults();
        }, 200 ) );
        // debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
        function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
            var timeout;
            return function debounced() {
                if ( timeout ) {
                    clearTimeout( timeout );
                }
                function delayed() {
                    fn();
                    timeout = null;
                }
                timeout = setTimeout( delayed, threshold || 100 );
            }
        }

        // Function to check if filters have some results
        function checkResults(){
          var visibleItemsCount = $container.data('isotope').$filteredAtoms.length;
          console.log(filters);
          if( visibleItemsCount > 0 ){
            $('.no-results').hide();
          }
          else{
            $('.no-results').show();
          }
        }
      
        //fancybox
        $('.fancybox2').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); // Default action ausschalten

            $.fancybox({
                //width: 500,
                //height: 400,
                autoSize: true,
                href: $(this).attr('href'),
                type: 'ajax'
            });
        });


        // Filter mit Select Form

        $select.change(function() {

            var $this = $(this);

            // store filter value in object
            // i.e. filters.color = 'red'
            var group = $this.attr('data-filter-group');

            filters[ group ] = $this.find(':selected').attr('data-filter-value');
            // console.log( $this.find(':selected') )
            // convert object into array
            var isoFilters = [];
            for ( var prop in filters ) {
              if( filters[ prop ] != '*' ){
                isoFilters.push( filters[ prop ] )
              }
            }
            SelectFilter = isoFilters.join('');
            $container.isotope();
            checkResults();
            return false;

        });
    });
```

```css
#lexikon-masonry .item {
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 5px;
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px #ccc solid;
    float: left;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
#lexikon-masonry .item img {
 opacity: 1;
}
#lexikon-masonry .item:hover img {
 opacity: 0.5;
}
#lexikon-masonry .image-hover #image-caption {
 position: relative; 
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 bottom: 0px;
 background: #fff;
 z-index: 1;
 opacity: 1;
 text-transform: uppercase;

}
#lexikon-masonry .image-hover:hover #image-caption {
 opacity: 0.8;
}
#lexikon-masonry .image-hover #image-caption span {
 text-transform: none;
}
#lexikon-masonry .image-hover .img-button-link {
 position: absolute; 
 /*left: 50%;
 top: 50%;*/
 margin-left: 110px;
 margin-top: -125px;
 opacity: 0;
}
#lexikon-masonry .image-hover:hover .img-button-link {
 opacity: 1;
}

.no-results{
  display:none;
}

div#lexikon-filter {
    position:left;
}

div.lexStyled { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    overflow:hidden; /* this hides the select's drop button */ 
    padding:0; 
    margin:0; 
    background: white url(../images/select-down.png) no-repeat bottom right; 
    /* this is the new drop button, in image form */ 
    width:12em; 
 border-radius:2px; 
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
    border: solid 1px #ccc; 
}

div.lexStyled select { 
    width:115% /* this percentage effectively extends the drop down button out of view */; 
    background-color:transparent /* this hides the select's background making any styling visible from the div */; 
    background-image:none; 
    -webkit-appearance: none /* this is required for Webkit browsers */; 
    border:none; 
    box-shadow:none; 
    padding:0.3em 0.5em; /* padding should be added to the select, not the div */ 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
 <div class="row">
  <div id="lexikon-suche" class="col span_3">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" data-filter-value="" id="quicksearch" placeholder="Durchsuchen" />
  </div>
  <div id="lexikon-filter" class="col span_9">
   <div class="lexStyled">
   <select data-filter-group="gestein">
    <option data-filter-value="*" class="selected">Alle Gesteine</option>
                <option data-filter-value=".lagersteine" class="selected">Lagersteine</option>
                <option data-filter-value=".kunststeine" class="selected">Kunststeine</option>

   </select>
   </div>
   <div class="lexStyled">
   <select data-filter-group="farbe">
    <option data-filter-value="*" class="selected">Alle Farben</option>
                <option data-filter-value=".rot" class="selected">Rot</option>
                <option data-filter-value=".gelb" class="selected">Gelb</option>

   </select>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
<br><hr><br>
 <div class="row">
  <div id="lexikon-masonry" class="col span_12">
    <div class="item image-hover lagersteine rot gelb">
     <div id="image-caption" class="name">Test1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item image-hover kunststeine rot">
     <div id="image-caption" class="name">Test2</div>
    </div>
            <div class="item image-hover lagersteine kunststeine gelb">
                <div id="image-caption" class="name">Test3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
        <div class="no-results">Sorry - we can't find any entries with this search filters!</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: great that's what i was looking for. thx Do you also know why in my example after setting the dropdown filter back to "alle" after the second dropdown the results become "0" and i have to reload the script? thx

Comment: Yes. If you reset filters to "alle", your `selectFilter` value becomes `**` and this has no matches. Change `SelRes` to `var SelRes = SelectFilter == '' || $(this).is(SelectFilter);` and don't add `*` to filter array. `if( filters[ prop ] != '*' ){isoFilters.push( filters[ prop ] )}`. See my snippet again, I edited it.

Comment: Wow i don't know how to say...! **Thank you!**

Comment: @ReneKorss would you mind checking out my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609689/isotope-show-error-if-no-results-found-by-filter

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Isotope v3, here is a solution that worked for me.

$grid = isotope container

```
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({...});
```

#no-results container

```
<div id="no-results">No results found.</div>
```

Check if no results on 'arrangeComplete'

```
$grid.on( 'arrangeComplete', function( event, filteredItems ) {
    if (filteredItems.length === 0) {
      $('#no-results').show();
    } else {
      $('#no-results').hide();
    }
});
```

Refer to Isotope docs for vanilla Javascript example:
https://isotope.metafizzy.co/events.html